# Javascript Dynamic Table with each cell having an onmouse event?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, onmouseover

I've created a dynamic table using Javascript.  Now what I'm trying to do is for each cell that is dynamically generated, there is an onmouseover event that would change that particular cell's backgroundColor.

The problem I have is that when I generate the table and try to have an onmouseover function with each dynamically generated cell the function only works for the last generated cell.

Here's a copy of my code.  (Note: I have only tested this on Chrome)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<style>
 table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
 }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var table;
 
 function init(){
  table = document.getElementById("mytable");
 }
 
 function makeCells(){
  init();
    
  for(var a=0;a<20;a++){
   var row = table.insertRow(-1);
   
   for(var b=0;b<20;b++){
    cell = row.insertCell(-1);
    cell.innerHTML = a*b;
    cell.onmouseover = function(){cell.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";};
   }
  }
 }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="javascript: makeCells();">
 <table id="mytable"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: Your problem is that `cell` always refers the last cell. It's a general `closure` problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some improvements. 3 things I would change:

1. Don't edit inline styles with javascript. Instead, add or remove a class. see # 3.
2. Don't do so many event handlers in your "onload", "onmouseover". Its better to add an event listener.
3. It is better performance to add all of the new elements at one time instead of individually. See this article: https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/reflow

Here is a way to optimize the Javascript:

HTML

```
<table id="table"></table>
```

CSS

```
body {
  padding: 40px;
}
.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}
td {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    outline: 1px solid black;
}
```

JavaScript

```
    function propegateTable() {
      var table = document.getElementById("table");
      
      //will append rows to this fragment
      var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

      for(var a=0; a<10; a++){ //rows
          //will append cells to this row
          var row = document.createElement("tr");

          for(var b=0;b<5;b++){ //columns
            var cell = document.createElement("td");
            cell.textContent = a + ", " + b;
            // event listener
            cell.addEventListener("mouseover", turnYellow);
            row.appendChild(cell);
          }

          fragment.appendChild(row);
        }
      //everything added to table at one time
      table.appendChild(fragment);
    }

    function turnYellow(){
      this.classList.add("yellow");
    }

    propegateTable();
```

http://codepen.io/ScavaJripter/pen/c3f2484c0268856d3c371c757535d1c3

Comment: Thanks scavaJripter!  I'll try out this way.  I'm just learning html,css and javascript so I'm not that well versed yet..

Comment: keep it up.. Just try to get javascript knowledge from MDN and not w3schools

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the answer myself playing around with my code.

In the line:

```
cell.onmouseover = function(){cell.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";};
```

I changed it to:

```
cell.onmouseover = function(){this.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";};
```

Answer (score 0):

It is generally [not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice) to use inline event handlers.

Using [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) (ED) you only need to assign a handler *once* on a level higher up the DOM tree (often `document` or `document.body`). A further advantage of ED may that you can assign handler(s) before the table rows/cells exist.

In the example the `mouseover` is replaced with the css `:hover` pseudo class.

A click handler is assigned for the table cells using the aforementioned ED.

```js
document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);
makeCells(document.querySelector(`#mytable`));

function handle(evt) {
  // only handle when the target is a table cell
  // AND it's a cell from table#mytable
  if (evt.target.closest(`td`).closest(`#mytable`)) {
    evt.target.classList.toggle(`selected`);
  }
}

function makeCells(forTable) {
  for (let a = 0; a < 20; a +=1 ) {
    forTable.insertRow(-1);
  }
  
  [...forTable.rows].forEach( (row, i) => {
    for (let b = 0; b < 10; b += 1) {
      row.insertAdjacentHTML(`beforeend`, `<td>r${i}/c${b}</td>`);
    }
  })
}
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

td:hover {
  color: blue;
}

td.selected {
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
}
```

```html
<table id="mytable"></table>
```